# Multi Level List on a TableView/CollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uicollectionview

have a multilevel list, where one object can have sub objects and these consecutively.

> - **object1**
> - **object2**
> - Group
>
>   - **Object4**
>   - Group
>
>     - **object5**
>     - **object6**
>     - **object7**
>     - **object8**
>   - **Object10**
> - **object11**
> - **object12**
> - **object13**

I need to present the object´s elements on a tableview/collectionview.

How can i present this strocuture on a tableview/collectionView **whitout the use of sections**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you think about "nest" collectionview/tableview in collectionview/tableview ? Like the photo library ? Where `objectx`would be a folder as `group` and `object` would be an ... object.

Comment: sorry but i need to present all the objectX. What you mean about a "nest" collection/tableview?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to literally answer your question, as opposed to suggesting alternatives, I would advise the following:

Top Level `UITableView` with two types of custom `UITableViewCell`s. The first would be the standard `object` cell, and the second would be the `group cell`. This group cell would itself have a `UITableView` inside of it, as well a `Group Label` above the `UITableView`.

I would then do the same for each UITableView, with the standard `object` cell, and then the cell with a `UITableView` and `UILabel` inside.

For the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method I would do a check to see if the cell at the `indexPath` is an object, and if so I imagine this would be a standard height. If it were a cell with a `UITableView` I would probably call a method I'd create in the custom cell such as:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForCellWithItems:(NSArray *)items
{
    CGFloat totalHeight;
    for (id item in items)
    {
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[ObjectExample class])
        {
            totalHeight += objectHeight;
        }

        else if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSArray class])
        {
            totalHeight += [self heightForCellWithItems:item];
        }
    }

    return totalHeight
}
```

I would return that for any cell whose height is determined by the amount of items in it.

For each custom cell that holds a tableView I would have a readwrite property called something like `items` and these are the items that would be used to populate the tableView. Once again though (assuming the way you are doing this is with arrays in arrays) every time it hit an array, it would pass that in to yet another nest cell with a tableView in it.

In the setter for the `items` property I would reloadData on the `tableView` in the cell.

Comment: can you explain better how you populate the "new" tableview inside the cell?

Comment: I am searching for the same.